# Why is my Flutter Future returning "Instance of Future<String>" instead of data from PHP file?

Tags: php, android, mysql, flutter, dart

I'm diving into Flutter and trying to fetch some data from my PHP backend. However, I'm encountering an unexpected issue. Instead of getting the actual data from my PHP file, my Flutter Future is returning "Instance of Future". Can't figure out what's going on.

Here's a snippet of my Flutter code:

```
    Future displayLg_name() async {
        var url = Uri.http(
            "192.168.68.216", '/ump_attendance_2/username.php', {'q': '{http}'});
        var response = await http.post(url, body: {
          "lg_username": username.lg_username,
        });
        if (response.body.isNotEmpty){
          return (json.decode(response.body));
        };
```

I'm trying to display it in my container

```
   Container(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Text(
            displayLg_name().toString(),
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black54,
              fontFamily: "Ubuntu",
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: scrwidth / 18,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

And here is my php file

```
            <?php
            include ("config.php");
            session_start();
            $lg_username = $_REQUEST['lg_username'];

            $sql = "SELECT lg_name FROM hr_login WHERE lg_username = '$lg_username'";

            $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($res)>0){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
                    echo json_encode($row['lg_name']);
                }
            }
            ?>
```

I've double-checked my PHP file, and it seems fine. Could someone help me spot where I might be going wrong in my Flutter code?

Appreciate any insights or suggestions!

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Comment: my bad. I accidentally put to much attention to solve error in flutter.. thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do something like this instead:

```dart
var text = await displayLg_name();
/* ... */
Container(
  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
  child: Text(
    text ?? '',
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black54,
      fontFamily: "Ubuntu",
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: scrwidth / 18,
    ),
  ),
),
```

**Edited**
If your class is *statefull*, you can declare it inside *initState()* like this:

```dart
var text;

void _init() async {
  await displayLg_name().then((value) => setState(() => text = value));
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _init();
}
```